# Load CSS and JS over HTTPS in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, http, ssl, https

One of my websites is in Wordpress. I setup SSL on the site. I would like the entire site be loaded via HTTP except 1 page lets call it PAYMENTS.

How can I achieve in Wordpress when I click in the menu PAYMENTS it loads it over HTTPS and also load all CSS and JS over HTTPS. Because when I did manually in the url: https://www.example.com/payments/ it loads without any CSS and JS because its all blocked due its loaded over HTTP in the source.

Also want to achieve that if I click in the menu any other item and it goes back to HTTP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use agnostic paths to your CSS and JS, e.g. `//` instead of `http://` when you are calling them.  Also, a great plugin called [WordPress HTTPS](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-https/installation/) can do the one-page-only https for you:

Comment: Where do I change http:// to // ? I can edit php files, I am just not skilled with Wordpress file sctructure where is what.

Comment: It depends - check your header.php for links to css and js files, and check functions.php to see if any scripts or styles are enqueued.  Start tracking down the unsecured requests by viewing your source code when you load the https page and see what calls are violating security.  Try using the plugin first, though - it should take care of the builtin WordPress script and css calls.

Comment: didnt work out with the plugin, when I view the source over HTTPS, all js and css and other elements are loaded via HTTP, dont know what to do...

Comment: Did you ensure that the page itself was set to load via https?  There's a checkbox on the right side when you go to edit that page.

Comment: Yes I did but that wont help, because I am running entire website on Wordpress and page example /support/ I need to run on HTTPS and thats a DJANGO app so in the Wordpress checking the box on page use HTTPS on support page is useless...

Comment: Ah, that would be important to know.  Unfortunately, I don't know enough about your setup and Django to help :( - try adding more of your setup information (such as, this is a Django App) to your question.

Comment: Thanks I found it in Django html template now it works, thank you :)

Answer (score 8):

You can get WordPress to use Protocol-Agonstic paths for CSS & JavaScript by adding this to your theme's functions.php:

```
add_filter('script_loader_src', 'agnostic_script_loader_src', 20,2);
function agnostic_script_loader_src($src, $handle) {
    return preg_replace('/^(http|https):/', '', $src);
}

add_filter('style_loader_src', 'agnostic_style_loader_src', 20,2);
function agnostic_style_loader_src($src, $handle) {
    return preg_replace('/^(http|https):/', '', $src);
}
```

Note this won't be respected by plugins like Better WordPress Minify that change how scripts & styles are included in the page, and this technique won't work with IE6 (which shouldn't be a concern these days anyway).

Comment: I added this to functions.php and nothing have happened all is loaded via HTTP even I am on HTTPS.

Comment: If this didn't work and WordPress HTTPS didn't work, it sounds like you have a poorly-coded theme that hard-codes the URLs to all of the Javascript and CSS resources instead of enqueuing them like you're supposed to in WordPress.